# C# калькулятор матриц на win forms выводит некорректный результат

Tags: c#, winforms

Суть программы такова, что пользователь на форме нажимает кнопки заполнения матрицы рандомными числами и выбирает через RadioButton действие. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку Выполнить выводятся рандомные числа не имеющие ничего общего с вычислениями. Хотя алгоритм вычисления действий над матрицами верный. Спасибо за внимание!

Форма:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView3.RowCount = 3;
    dataGridView3.ColumnCount = 3;
    dataGridView2.RowCount = 3;
    dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 3;
    dataGridView1.RowCount = 3;
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillDataGridView(AppLogic.mat1, dataGridView1);
}

private void FillDataGridView(int[,] arr, DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    AppLogic.FillArr(arr);

    dataGridView.RowCount = arr.GetLength(0);
    dataGridView.ColumnCount = arr.GetLength(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = arr[i, j];
}

private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells[0].Selected = false;
    }
    catch { }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillDataGridView(AppLogic.mat2, dataGridView2);
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        AppLogic.Addition();
        FillDataGridView(AppLogic.mat, dataGridView3);
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        AppLogic.Subtraction();
        FillDataGridView(AppLogic.mat, dataGridView3);
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Выберите действие!", "Предупреждение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Статический класс AppLogic:

```
public const int ROWS = 3;
public const int COLS = 3;

public static int[,] mat1 = new int[ROWS, COLS];
public static int[,] mat2 = new int[ROWS, COLS];
public static int[,] mat = new int[ROWS, COLS];

static Random rnd = new Random();

public static void FillArr(int[,] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            arr[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 20);
}

public static void Addition()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            mat[i, j] = mat1[i, j] + mat2[i, j];
}

public static void Subtraction()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            mat[i, j] = mat1[i, j] - mat2[i, j];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void FillDataGridView(int[,] arr, DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    AppLogic.FillArr(arr); // - вот эта строчка что делает с AppLogic.mat?
```

Comment: Заполняет матрицу рандомными числами. Описал в отдельной функции, чтобы не повторяться в заполнении два раза, т.к. две матрицы.

Comment: @SergeiArhipenko Ну вот Вы и заполняете матрицу результата случайными числами перед тем, как ее показать в гриде.

Comment: Невнимательный дурак, спасибо!!!

Comment: @SergeiArhipenko Пожалуйста. Успехов.